# Generate Pick & Pack List of Ordered Items in Magento, and send to Third-Party Logistics Company

Tags: php, magento, customization

In Magento, is it possible to provide a Pick & Pack list of items of available completed orders, to the 3rd-party Logistics company?

There are, however, some additional problems which are:-

- Which all 3rd-party logistics companies be available & how? Will they be registered as customers or will they be available in some other way in Magento (just like Customers, but with very minimal permissions)?
- How will they be provided with the Pick & Pack List? Will they be mailed or they can view the list in some way in the Admin?
- If they (3rd-party logistics companies) are provided with login in the Magento admin, then they can also provide the Tracking Number of the dispatched goods.

All queries & answers are welcome, and many thanks in advance to all of you for providing any suitable / probable way.

Comment: This is not a programming question but rather discussion that suits to magento forums. Feel free to go through first point from FAQ that you can find from top bar of this site. Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …

Comment: @Anton - Thanks for the downvote. As regards to your programming question, these sort of question often leads to programming answers (containing **a bit of source code in them**, for examples or for highlighting the way to proceed). So that's why I posted the question here.

Comment: you are welcome, to answer it non programming way: it's possible you just need to think how you would like it to be handled in your specific workflow and the rest is just programming, testing and integrating

Comment: @Anton - :) What are the options that can be used to make it handle in a general way? That's where my main problem lies, as client himself is unknown to what are its option.

Comment: have you searched magento connect for already available extensions that do exactly this?

Comment: @Anton - :( many a times, with different keywords, but in vain

Comment: wel, if none found you better start with flow and feature analysis with your client and get a book that explains best practices as you are not ready to ask programming questions jet

Comment: @Anton - :) Still I will look out for any source of light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we actually make a Magento extension which does exactly what you are looking for.

For 3rd party access I would recommend setting up a new admin user account with only permissions set to view sales>orders, they can then log in, add the tracking number (if you want them to do that), and then print picklists for the relevant orders. They can print one where all items are combined by sku, and one where all orders are summarized by order.

Give me a shout if you have any more questions. (our website is www.moogento.com)

Comment: Thanks very much, for the logic provided. As of no, it's in dormant stage, but will definitely get back to you if needed. Thanks again!